# JQuery AJAX request to Sinatra app blocked by CORS

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, sinatra, cors

I have been struggling with this for quite sometime now.  I believed I had the issue resolved, but lo and behold, it arised again.

Here is my problem from localhost:

```
OPTIONS http://my.server.com/authorize Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my.server.com/authorize. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I am trying to make a request from a client to my Sinatra application.  My client code is as follows:

```
function authorize(token)
{
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://my.server.com/authorize/authorize",
    crossDomain: "true",
    jsonp: "false",
    async: true,
    headers: {"Authorization" : token},
    success: function(data){
      console.log("success");
      window.location = (envHost+"/fb/authenticate");
    }
  });
}
```

In my Sinatra application I made an effort to enable CORS.  I have tried both of the following ways:

```
options '/*' do
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] ="accept, authorization, origin"
end
```

and

```
before do  
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'accept, authorization, origin'
end
```

Even in my Apache Passenger VirtualHost I made the following addition

```
  <Directory    /var/Developer/MySite/public>
   Options     -MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Allow       from all
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "accept, authorization, origin"
  </Directory>
```

This has been a pain in the neck. If anyone has guidance, it would be much appreciated on why CORS will not work.

Comment: You don't need `jsonp: false` or `async: true`(true by default), or even `crossdomain: true`(true by default if it's a cross-domain request, which it is). Are you getting the same result in all browsers?

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I made the modification, and the problems still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer to my problem.  Initially, I was adding the header information to the Passenger web server via my sites-available/defaults file, **and** the Sinatra web service routes.  Having set the CORS response headers in both places caused my response headers to have duplicate header information about the allowed origin, methods, etc.

Once I removed the headers from the web server, and left them on the web service routes, my requests went through.